# Cross-validating lm model and returning an lm class in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, lm, predict

Suppose I'm trying to do some cross validation and have a training set and a validation set. Maybe something like this:

```
full_data = read.csv("data/my_data.csv")
in_training_data = sample(1:nrow(full_data), size=.67*nrow(full_data))
training_set = full_data[in_training_data,]
validation_set = full_data[!(1:nrow(full_data) %in% in_training_data),]
```

What I want to do is estimate the fit with `training_set`, then pass `validation_set` into a new model *without refitting the data*. Something like this would be ideal:

```
initial_model = lm(y~x+z, data=training_set)
validation_model = lm(y~x+z, data=validation_set, model=initial_model, refit=FALSE)
```

If this were the case, I could use all the same functions on `validation_model` that I could on `initial_model` (`coef`, `summary`, etc.). Alas, the documentation doesn't have "model" or "refit" options.

I could, of course, use `predict` to estimate the new fitted values:

```
new_fits = predict(initial_model, newdata = validation_model)
```

And that's fine, but it only returns the fitted values. With some R ninja moves, I could create a function that basically recreates the `lm` class, but that seems quite cumbersome.

I could also use `offset` to fix the parameters of the model, but that doesn't return r squared, the original coefficients, or many of the other objects contained within a traditional `lm`.

So, **is there a way to refit an old model to a new dataset and return an `lm` class?** Is my only option to basically recreate the `lm` class using the output of the `predict` function?

And, to preempt potential answers, I know about k-fold cross-validation, but that's not what I want. I don't want an algorithm that does the split/estimation for me. I already have the split and just want to feed it into a new model.

Comment: have you checked out `?update` to see if that does the trick for you?

Comment: Update will re-estimate the coefficients, which I *don't want*.